# Why Killua didn't use Knov abilities?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

After watching episode 143 I wondered.
Assuming Knov also wishes to Gon full recovery, If Killua would contact Knov from the start he could use his abilities to teleport himself to Alluka and take her directly to Gon, or at least plan with him in advance to meet him on the road to the hospital and by that he will no longer needed to struggle escaping Illumi.

Comment: AFAIK knov cannot teleport himself what he have as ability is the ability to create a space of its own within a certain area along with multiple entrances and exits so its limit and would not be reachable from killua's home to the hospital. I do agree that it would be of help using that to meet killua somewhere within the skirts of the city but.

Comment: Not to mention, this episode it was mentioned that if alluka was spotted by anyone that they would take her home immediately which is also why they were asked to have the hospital completely empty.

Comment: @Prix Knov can move himself as well. He is shown doing so earlier in the series.

Comment: @キルア he needs to set entrance and exit points? Isn't the distance of entrance and exits area limited based on the start point? wouldn't he need to keep coming out and in to set up new points? if all that would be required illumi and hisoka would get him at some point

Comment: @Prix I'm not saying it's feasible in this case, but during the Chimera Ant arc, when he was creating portals for the team to move about, he was seen using them as well.

Comment: I think so too I am more curious in regards its limitations which I am not sure of, but it seemed he was tied to a start point to me where his dungeon was set

Comment: @Prix It is well known that Knov can create portals in advance. So like I said earlier, They could at least meet in the middle of the road to the hospital. Besides, Killua could use him for a fail safe solution.
The only question is why he didn't do it (consider how much easy it will be)?.

Comment: 2 factors you are not considering 1) the limitations of knov ability 2) the fact that if alluka was to be in touch to anyone outside Killua's family they would return her home immediately as said in the last episode.

Comment: @Prix 1. What limitations are there? Knov could place his long range portal in the hospital (like he did in the ant palace) and wait for Killua on a planned location.
2. Maybe Alluka should have to return home, But at least Killua will able to cure Gon (I believe it's more important to him...)

Comment: Knov limits aside, breaking family rules is a direct conflict with his Dad & Gramps. Killua's disobedience would unnecessarily raise Alluka's (who isn't considered family) risk of being recaptured or exterminated. Illumi is one thing, the parents are another. So Risk assessment is one reason not to use Knov's abilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During all that arc, Killua is under the surveillance of his family and he is forbidden to show the abilities of Alluka or even talk about her or let people see her (e.g. a butler of the family interrupted a phone call where Killua could talk about Alluka, nobody except persons related to her family saw Alluka when she went in the hospital). If Killua disobeys them, Alluka and also himself will be forced to return at their family mansion.

Like you said in a comment, he could still have tried to cure Gon that way and return home with Alluka then but there are some points for which he can't let that happen :

1) There was still a risk that his family caught him before he cured Gon, so if he failed he couldn't help him anymore.
2) Alluka is the only member of his family that Killua really likes and she sees her brother as a good person so he doesn't want to disappoint her.
3) If Alluka was caught by Illumi, he would use the power of his sister for himself without caring about her. And Killua couldn't allow that to happen.

Comment: I see, from your answer it's looks like he have to choose cure Gon or protect Alluka or trying extremely hard to save both of them.